# Can an async function run at the same time as another instance of it is running?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So I have a function like this in a singleton service that is injected into a controller.

```
public async Task<ResponseModel> Put(BoardModel request)
{
    var board = await dbService.GetBoardAsync(request.UserId, request.TargetId, request.Ticker);

    // Update the model
    // ...

    var response = await dbService.SetBoardAsync(request.UserId, request.TargetId, request.Ticker, request);

    return new ResponseModel
    {
        ResponseStatus = response.Successful(replacements: 1) ? ResponseStatus.Success : ResponseStatus.Failure
    };
}
```

What I'm worried about is race conditions, say if two instances of the function are running at the same time, and one overwrites the entry in the db.

Is this possible? There's a very small chance of it happening, but I'm still a bit worried.

Thanks!

Comment: Then use appropriate locking levels or concurrency options on the database.  There's no guarantees in this code that it can't be run twice, async or synchronously.

Comment: @DavidL this a web application. Even if it *wasn't* marked with async, multiple HTTP PUT requests result in multiple calls. There's no reason for locking

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you misunderstood.  Not a code lock, a database lock.  If the OP is worried about transactional data being overwritten or being out of date, they need to handle it at the database level, NOT the web app level.

Comment: @Shreeyam concurrent PUT requests will result in concurrent execution of the Put method even if you *don't* use the `async` keyword. You have to write your data access code properly to handle concurrent modifications. What *do* you want to do if two PUT methods arrive against the *same* database record? Drop one? Allow it? Check their order?

Comment: @DavidL even worse, besides you can't use database locks directly. You have to use either pessimistic (transactions) or optimistic concurrency (rowversion checks) methods. Both are supported by EF and other ORMs

Comment: @Shreeyam what ORM are you using? EF allows both pessimist and optimistic concurrency. This question is 100% about your data access

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using a document database which doesn't even support locking. I think I'll move to Couchbase or something instead which supports locking. Thanks!

Comment: @Shreeyam Why ? You *don't* need locks for this. ALL databases have concurrency mechanisms, *especially* document databases. Which one are you using? For example, you can use an ETAG value or the equivalent as a rowversion, only updating the row it the versions match.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using RethinkDb

Comment: @Shreeyam besides you can't access database locks in *any* database. They are implementation details which you can see for administration purposes but never affect directly

Comment: Consider using CQRS with Event Sourcing and separate stores for read and write operations. Works well in highly concurrent systems. Combined with Akka.net/Project Orleans or Orleankka it's pretty powerful

Comment: @Shreeyam check this [discussion](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/5286) from the RethinkDB site - you can hand-code optimistic concurrency but ... RethinkDB isn't supposed to work like this. If you want to increment a value, you should do just that, not load an entire record then update it. A `somefield = somefield +1` type of update isn't affected by concurrent executions.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hmn, yeah. The update command in RethinkDb so maybe passing in an anonymous function there would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming your server has more than one thread (which will be any production capable web server), then two or more threads can be simultaneously running the same block of code. The typical way to handle this type of situation is with optimistic concurrency. What that means is that EF will attempt to save the record (*optimistically* assuming it will be able to without issue), and if the record ends up having been modified before it got to it, it will return an exceptions (specifically `OptimisticConcurrencyException`). You can see [this ASP.NET getting started article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) for a walkthrough on how to set it up. Essentially, it just involves adding a `rowversion` column to your database table(s). Each time the row is updated, the value of that column mutates. Therefore, EF can check the value on the record it's trying to update with what's currently on the table. If they're the same, it can continue updating. If not, then something else modified the record and it stops the update. By catching the exception that's returned, you can then respond appropriately by reloading the data and trying to do another update.

It's highly unlikely you would end up hitting a concurrency issue multiples times, but just in case, I would recommend using something like [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) ([Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Polly)) to handle the exception. Among other things, it allows you retry a set number of times or even forever, until no exception is raised. This then would ensure that the record would eventually get updated, even if there were multiple concurrency conflicts.

```
Policy
  .Handle<OptimisticConcurrencyException>()
  .RetryForever((exception, context) => {
      // resolve concurrency issue
      // See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904.aspx
  })
  .Execute(() => {
      db.SaveChanges();
  });
```